# i'm having trouble with battery not charging

Tags: battery

I think I have a battery going bad. Charged over nite and light read charged. 
but in the first 15 mins  it died on me

how long does it take to charge a hitachi battery 18v

Comment: How old is it?  It’s probably time.....

Comment: Lithium Ion battery's are best to run all the way down before charging up again. If I can recall they typically last longer by charging to 80% and not 100%. You will see that 80% number with Electric Vehicles quite a  bit and I think it is for that reason .